# SONARQUBE result analysis

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

Situation
I have a jenkins server and a sonarqube server.
I want if number of bugs reported in the current build by sonarqube are more than that of the previous build, my build should fail.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? You're most likely not the first person in the world to try this and should be able to find some starting point on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

This is what quality gates are for: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Gates

You can define conditions that must be met, also in your case "no bugs on new code".

However I am not sure if you can feedback quality gate result to your Jenkins build since Sonarqube has some post processing happening once your Jenkins job is finished.

Comment: In fact, there is a SonarQube plugin to do this, but using it will tie up a Jenkins executor for an indeterminate length of time, which is why SonarSource does not recommend its use. SonarQube 6.2 also introduces WebHooks, to POST notifications after server-side processing is done.